# How to get message value in gRPC stream interceptor

Tags: go, grpc

I have implement a gRPC stream interceptor in Server like this:

```golang
// Service define:
// rpc searchProducts(google.protobuf.StringValue) returns (stream Product);

func (w *wrappedStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    log.Printf("%T, %v", m, m)
    return w.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m)
}

// Log print:
// *wrapperspb.StringValue,
```

It can print the message type using `%T` correctly, but the message value printing by `%v` is just a blank.

I'm  sure that Server received the right message, because it replied Client the right thing.

The interceptor wrapper `RecvMsg` is not working in Client too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m)` will unmarshall data into `m`, just move print after `RecvMsg()` call.

```golang
func (w *wrappedStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    err := w.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m)
    log.Printf("%T, %v", m, m)
    return err
}
```